# UTF-8 BOM Problem

Tags: utf-8

I am using Komodo Edit. I have to encode some files as UTF-8 without BOM in Komodo. In my localhost and site there is no problem but on some sites i am seeing BOM sign and this is a terrible problem for AJAX-JSON response.
Any advices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The option can be found in the Properties section of the File Properties and Settings dialog box.

[image: File Properties and Settings]